# Insert lines of file into multi-line selection (visual block mode) in Vim

Tags: vim

Let us assume that file 'file.txt' contains:

```
31
37
14
```

I would like to insert those lines into certain places of a Vim buffer (using perhaps visual block mode with Ctrl-v ??).
In other words, if file 'text.txt' contains

```
This is the beginning of a file with several lines
Age of Person A: ; Other info...
Age of Person B: ; Other info...
Age of person C: ; Other info...
This is the end of the file.
```

is it possible to insert the corresponding lines of 'file.txt' into the places before the ';' character at each selected line?

The desired result would be:

```
This is the beginning of a file with several lines
Age of Person A: 31; Other info...
Age of Person B: 37; Other info...
Age of person C: 14; Other info...
This is the end of the file.
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! Just highlight the numbers in visual block mode (`C-v`):

```
31
37
14
```

Yank them (`y`) and in normal mode place your cursor where I've put a `|`
symbol below:

```
This is the beginning of a file with several lines
Age of Person A:|; Other info...
Age of Person B: ; Other info...
Age of person C: ; Other info...
This is the end of the file.
```

and use the put command (`p`). You'll end up with:

```
This is the beginning of a file with several lines
Age of Person A: 31; Other info...
Age of Person B: 37; Other info...
Age of person C: 14; Other info...
This is the end of the file.
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are editing `text.txt`…

1. Edit `file.txt`:

   ```
   :e file.txt<CR>
   ```
2. Select the lines in visual-block mode:

   ```
   <C-v>Gl
   ```
3. Yank the block:

   ```
   y
   ```
4. Switch back to `text.txt`:

   ```
   <C-^> (or <C-6>, or :b#<CR>)
   ```
5. Move the cursor to where you want those numbers.

   ```
   /;<CR>
   ```
6. Put the yanked text before the cursor:

   ```
   P
   ```

Reference:

```
:help :edit
:help visual-block
:help G
:help l
:help ctrl-^
:help /
:help P
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as an alternative answer, you may not have known (I didn't till now) that you can create Vim macros that work across files/splits.

For this problem, you can create a split to put the two files next to each other in the same Vim session:
[image: Vim - vsplit view]

Then on the destination file, move the cursor to the first line you want to modify, in this case `Age of Person A`. Now press `q` and any letter of your choosing to record the macro at that letter. Then once it's recording, I typed  the following
`^Whggdd^Wlpkf;d$jpkJ` to go to the left window `^Wh` (`^W` is `ctrl+W`), go to top line `gg`, cut line `dd`, move back to right window `^Wl`, paste and rearrange the lines to get them in the right order `pkf;d$jpkJ`. Then I pressed `q` to stop the macro, and now you can apply the macro to every line you want with `@` and the letter you stored the macro in. In my case, I just did a visual block on the remaining lines and then typed `:norm @a`, since `a` was the letter I chose for my macro.

A little hackier, but the macros across files and splits might be useful feature to know.